# AWS Step Function returns condition path references error

Tags: json, function, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I am running step functions with two choices in AWS Step Functions.

```
...
"ChoiceState": {
  "Type" : "Choice",
  "Choices": [
    {
      "Variable": "$[0].input",
      "NumericEquals":1,
      "Next": "FirstMatchState"
    },
    {
      "Variable": "$[0].input",
      "NumericEquals":2,
      "Next": "SecondMatchState"
    }
  ],
  "Default": "DefaultState"
},
...
```

choice state entered with this input

```
//ChoiceStateEntered

{
"name": "ChoiceState",
"input": 1
}
```

Error thrown

```
{
 "error": "States.Runtime",
 "cause": "An error occurred while executing the state 'ChoiceState'      (entered at the event id #7). Invalid path '$[0].input': The choice state's condition path references an invalid value."
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply, you do not need $[0] but $.  Per your input, you should use $.input instead of $[0].input

Comment: Thanks. Can you point to any documentation for the choice variable field? I found this but it doesnt specify valid variable paths: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-choice-state.html#amazon-states-language-choice-state-rules

Comment: Here is the detailed explanation of input/output paths
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-input-output-filtering.html

Comment: thanks for the link. The part I was missing was that defining the variable field uses JSON paths.