# aws step function choice invalid path

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

Having a similar issue to this post: [AWS Step Function returns condition path references error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46966967/aws-step-function-returns-condition-path-references-error)

However, I am still getting the same error.

**Step code:**

```
{
 "StartAt": "get_active_facebook_ad_accounts_lambda",
 "States": {
   "get_active_facebook_ad_accounts_lambda": {
     "Type": "Task",
     "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
     "Parameters": {
       "FunctionName": "gods_country"
      },
     "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
     "Next": "ChoiceState"
},
   "ChoiceState": {
     "Type" : "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$.input",
          "NumericEquals": 1,
          "Next": "DefaultState"
        },
        {
          "Variable": "$.input",
          "NumericEquals": 0,
          "Next": "EndState"
        }
      ]
  },
   "DefaultState": {
      "Type": "Fail"
   },
   "EndState": {
     "Type": "Succeed"
   }
}
}
```

**Execution plan errors:**
[image]

Comment: Try `$.Payload.input`. My guess is that `Variable` applies to the original object, not to the output of your lambda function.

Comment: Invalid path '$.Payload.input @lexicore

Comment: Is the input value returned by the code of Task "get_active_facebook_ad_accounts_lambda"???

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your function is just returning a number. If this is the case you can likely do something like this:

```json
{
 "StartAt": "get_active_facebook_ad_accounts_lambda",
 "States": {
   "get_active_facebook_ad_accounts_lambda": {
     "Type": "Task",
     "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
     "Parameters": {
       "FunctionName": "gods_country"
      },
     "ResultPath": "$.activeAccounts",
     "Next": "ChoiceState"
},
   "ChoiceState": {
     "Type" : "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$.activeAccounts",
          "NumericEquals": 1,
          "Next": "DefaultState"
        },
        {
          "Variable": "$.activeAccounts",
          "NumericEquals": 0,
          "Next": "EndState"
        }
      ]
  },
   "DefaultState": {
      "Type": "Fail"
   },
   "EndState": {
     "Type": "Succeed"
   }
}
}
```

`OutputPath` is used to only pass a portion of the result on to the next step. So your previous state machine was looking for a property called `Payload` coming from the result of your lambda. I don't think this is the case - it looks like the result is just a number.

`ResultPath` specifies where the result of the step should be stored, and allows us to combine this result with any previous state. In this case in `$.activeAccounts`. You can then reference that property in subsequent steps.

For further information check out [the AWS filtering documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-input-output-filtering.html)